# Activeadmin restrict access to non superuser items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using ActiveAdmin on Rails and I'm trying to lock down the section of the site which maintains admin users to non superusers.

Naturally I can hide the menu option like this:

```
ActiveAdmin.register AdminUser do
  menu :parent => "Settings", :if => proc { current_admin_user.superuser }
end
```

However the route still works if you bypass the menu and go directly to /admin/admin_users

What is the best practice to lock down the routes and controller for admins in ActiveAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried cancan: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan? There a gist with perfect example: https://gist.github.com/1264060

Comment: What if we want to avoid cancan? I'm struggling to find a way to register a before_filter on a resource so that I can just check that the current_user.administrator? Cancan seems overkill in this instance.

Answer (score 16):

You can add a before_filter to a controller block where the resource is registered, this is working for me:

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do

  menu :if => proc{ current_user.superadmin? }

  controller do
    before_filter :superadmin_filter

    def superadmin_filter
      raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found') unless current_user.superadmin?
    end
  end
```

[source](https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/issues/1108)

Comment: Since I got here from Google I'd like to point out that this worked just right for me, it basically disables the UserAdmin CRUD for any non-superadmin user. With recent Rails versions `before_filter` should be changed for `before_action`, though, the rest works just fine.

Comment: +1 @Oxfist I'm working with `Rails 5.2.2` and changing `before_filter` to `before_action` was necessary.

Answer (score 2):

@Tom Power's solution is great but I recommend storing it in the config: `config/initializers/active_admin.rb`

```
ActiveAdmin.setup do |config|
  def ensure_admin!
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found') unless current_user.superadmin?
  end

  config.before_action :ensure_admin!      
end
```

Comment: I went with this variant but moved `ensure_admin!` to `ApplicationController`.